# Error init SpringBoot 2.1.8.RELEASE using actuator

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-boot-actuator

I have a SpringBoot 2.1.8.RELEASE, but when I start the app. I got this error:

```
2019-10-01 10:38:24.373 ERROR 16232 --- [           main] d.c.b.a.s.c.d.InstanceDiscoveryListener  : Couldn't register instance for discovered instance...
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://127.0.0.1:2222${server.contextPath}/actuator/health
        at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852)
        at de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.cloud.discovery.EurekaServiceInstanceConverter.getHealthUrl(EurekaServiceInstanceConverter.java:45)
```

and I have this properties defined in my yml file

```
server:
  port: 2222
  servlet:
    contextPath:
```

Comment: check for spaces. This error you get when yaml formatting/spaces are not correct

Comment: but should complain for ${server.servlet.contextPath}, not ${server.contextPath}

Comment: What does your eureka service url look like in your configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove

```
 servlet:
     contextPath:
```

and try hitting your API.

If you want default path of the application then

```
servlet:
 contextPath: /api
```

Then your API looks like :

```
http://127.0.0.1:2222/api/actuator/health
```

Comment: did it with same result

Answer (score 0):

Change the yml file as below and try:

```
server:
  port: 2222
  servlet.context-path: /
```

Comment: did it with same result